# Want sharepoint documents to be from a folder that is created by oculus scanning software

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

my scenario is that I have a scanner that uses oculus software, the software scans into a folder, now want this folder to be a source of documents for sharepoint. 
Is it possible?

am using sharpoint 2010 enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All document SharePoint are stored in database besides you configure BLOB cache on your server. As mantioned [@mike](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2853/mike) to resolve this you need to push scenned documents to SharePoint useing API model of SharePoint.

You can do this using next code in your windows service:

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://testsite.dev"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Debug.txt"))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int) fs.Length);

                    SPList list = web.GetList("Lists/Test AAD");
                    SPFile f = list.RootFolder.Files.Add("/Shared Documents/"+Path.GetFileName(fs.Name), buffer);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: That's a nice answer, but you don't have to use SharePoint API, we just used a simple `SMTPClient` and pushed the file through as an attachment programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup. For every file that gets uploaded to a folder, we developed a windows service that will target that folder and everything that gets posted to it will email to a SharePoint document library, then delete the file in the folder. It works pretty well for us assuming you have the service automatically running. The web service is just using `StreamReader` and `SmtpClient` classes